# Merge Captured video stream of 2 html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, webrtc, mediastream

I am building a whiteboard app for a web conferencing app. All the libraries that I have investigated uses 2 canvas , 1 on the top for drawing and 1 in the bottom for holding the older drawings(for better performance since the upper canvas gets cleared on every draw).

Now I need to stream the content of these canvases for the other uses so they can see the content live.

### Option1 :

`captureStream` from each canvas and merge the videtracks into a single stream, `new MediaStream([...bottomTracks, ...topTracks])`, transfer the stream using webrtc and then extract the tracks from the stream, create a new stream for each track `new MediaStream([stream.getVideoTracks()[0]])`  and play the streams on absolutely positioned video elements. It works but my boss doesn't like it, don't know why? yet!
Is there a downside to this?

### Option2:

Create a third off screen canvas and periodically `drawImage` of the both canvas's on the offscreen canvas and then `captureStream` from that canvas!

So is there a better way or another way to achieve this?

### Update : Why Am I Using 2 canvases?

There only 1 reason, not to redraw everything again if I want to change something that is already drawn, what would change you might ask?
In 2 scenarios for me:

1. Smoothing the line that has been finished drawing by mousedrag,touchmove or pen (to make it feel more like a natural writing, checkout http://fabricjs.com/freedrawing)
2. Draw shapes by mousedrag, touchmove or pen

I know that I can redraw everything on every change but I believe it would have low performance on low end devices.

2 canvases are positioned absolutely on top of each other, The actual user drawings are done on the upper canvas and when its done and any enhancements needed are applied to it, the line/shape gets drawn on the bottom canvas and the upper canvas is cleared.

Comment: The best would be to have a single canvas being rendered to screen to begin with. Not sure what anyone thought the benefit would be to show two different canvases, but they anyway have to be composited by the painter, so better do it yourself directly. Also, for the first solution the obvious drawback is that you send twice more data over the network. Instead of having only one video feed, you get two. (Plus it's not certain both your video tracks will get preserved doing this like that, but you could send both as their own MediaStream anyway).

Comment: @Kaiido 2 canvas is used mainly to draw shapes by dragging and smoothout the lines after they have been drawn

Comment: Doesn't explain why two canvas are being rendered on the screen. The compositing could be done on the rendered canvas directly by your code.

Comment: @Kaiido once you render something on a canvas you can't change it anymore (like drawing on a paper) you have to clear the entire canvas and render everything again, you also have to keep a list of everything that has been drawn before so you can draw them again

Comment: Hum.. ;-) I know pretty well how the 2D canvas works, thanks. Back to my point: yes you can use multiple canvases as buffers, but only one need to be rendered in the page. When you overlay two canvases in the page, the page's renderer will have to do the compositing itself, at the same time it will composite everything else in the page. This will be an harder operation than compositing once outside of the layout. It will also fix your issue. (Ps: for a drawing board you should be able to redraw everything every frame anyway).

Comment: @Kaiido updated the post with more details

Comment: That still doesn't explain why you don't just do `visibleContext.drawImage( hiddenCanvas, 0, 0 );`

Comment: @Kaiido because I don't understand your logic, what `hiddenCanvas` is used for? could you provide a short sample? It does not have to work but just to visualize what you have in your mind

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/90fkumns/

Comment: @Kaiido now we talking, looks nice, I will try it, tnx

Answer (score -1):

As noted in the comments by kaiido, you only need one canvas on the screen.

In [record.a.video](https://record.a.video) I superimpose 2 video streams (screen video and camera video) onto one canvas. I then use another Media Stream to extract the video from the canvas and share as a VOD or to livestream.

Note that audio must be handled differently, as it is played in the Canvas.

Comment: This a totally different scenario